# Kexec immediately after Kickstart install (where is cmdline?)

Tags: rhel, kernel, kickstart, pxe, installer-anaconda

I used to be able to kexec into a new kernel immediately after a kickstart (anaconda) install via pxe.

I was able to do this by figuring out the current kernel version, and grabbing cmdline options by using /boot/grub/grub.conf

`cmdline=$(awk /kernel.*console/'{$1=$2=""; print$0}' /boot/grub/grub.conf)`

Then:
`kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) --initrd=/boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img --append="${cmdline}"`

Now I am unable to find what the cmdline options for the next reboot are since /proc/cmdline and the cmdline command only show me what the cmdline is for the installation disc.

How would I be able to find out what the cmdline is for next reboot now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
reboot --kexec
```

in your [kickstart file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html#idp31154112).

This should be equivalent to your previous approach, i.e. the kickstart software then figures out the kexec parameters for the newly installed system.

Comment: see also https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1424730 for a related issue when using this directive with Fedora 25